# Dumping XML from HttpRequest into a text file

Tags: xml, vba, httprequest, xml-documentation

I am requesting some XML from Ebay, but the returned XML is too long for VBA debug window, therefore I need to dump the returned XML to a file - being a n00b & grasping in the dark, I could do with someone helping me out with the correct syntax to take the contents of the XMLHttpRequest.responseXML.XML & put it into a file. Here's the code I have (which all works - I just need the line to write to a file)

```
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oFile As Object
Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile("Z:\AccessData\Temp.xml")     

XMLHttpRequest.send (body)
objxmldoc.loadXML (XMLHttpRequest.responseXML.XML)
Debug.Print XMLHttpRequest.responseXML.XML ' valid XML showing at this point
```

Answer (score 5):

Do you meant to save data to a file.Then this will do. Pass the XML as a string to a file.

```
Sub your_function()

Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oFile As Object
Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile("Z:\AccessData\Temp.xml") 

Dim sResult as String
XMLHttpRequest.send (body)
sResult = XMLHttpRequest.responseText()
SaveToFile "d:\AccessData\Temp.xml", sResult

End Sub

Sub SaveToFile(sFileName, sContent)
    'Saves a string to a file and closes the file
    ' sample usage: SaveToFile "d:\test.txt", "test"
    Dim fs As Object
    Dim file As Object
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set file = fs.CreateTextFile(sFileName, True)
    file.WriteLine (sContent)
    file.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to parse `objxmldoc.loadXML (XMLHttpRequest.responseXML.XML)` as `XMLHttpRequest.responseXML` already is a DOM document and of course if you need to save it to a file all you need is call the `save` method, as in `XMLHttpRequest.responseXML.save("result.xml")` (I am not really a VBA guy so currently not sure whether `XMLHttpRequest.responseXML.save "result.xml"` is the right syntax, but calling the `save` method is what you need).

Comment: Thanks, actually you gave me a good lead, which has resulted in a solution of sorts for me. I couldn't find the correct syntax for saving XMLHttpRequest.responseXML.XML, but these two concurrent commands do the job...    objxmldoc.loadXML (XMLHttpRequest.responseXML.XML)
     objxmldoc.Save "Z:\temp.xml"

Comment: Simply call the `save` method on the `responseXML`, there is absolutely no need to first use the to parse `responseXML.xml` with `loadXML`. So doing `XMLHttpRequest.responseXML.save "Z:\temp.xml"` should suffice and perform much better than first accessing `.xml`, then parse that with `.loadXML` to then `.save` that back.

Comment: The parsing entry is needed for the rest of the code (not for the saving of the file)

Comment: I don't see what you would achieve with that parsing step. the `responseXML` property gives you an MSXML DOM document directly, you don't gain anything by creating a second and parsing the serialization `.xml` of the first with `loadXML` into a second document.